# JPos Client in web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jpos

I am new to JPOS here. Currently what I want to do is to create a web service (Restful) as a client to send request to a JPOS Server for ISO transaction.

Any suggestion of where should I start with this? or any guide I can follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by reading http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf then http://jpos.org/doc/jPOS-EE.pdf and probably playing with the 'clientsimulator' and 'serversimulator' modules. Once you understand those, you can add the 'jetty' module and implement the REST part.

This link may also help: http://jpos.org/blog/2013/10/eating-our-own-dogfood/

Answer (score 0):

You can go [Jpos Site](http://www.jpos.org/tutorials) and follow 
Jetty and REST support [pdf]

**Shows you how to use jPOS-EE's Jetty module in order to provide a REST API.**

[pdf](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-rest.pdf)